# extracting a column as a vector from a matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a csv file , which I am converting it to a matrix using the following command:

```
reader = csv.reader(open("spambase_X.csv", "r"), delimiter=",")
x = list(reader)
result = numpy.array(x)
print(result.shape)   #outputs (57,4601)
```

Now I want to extract the first column of the matrix result , which I am doing by the following:

```
col1=(result[:, 1])

**print(col1.shape)        #outputs (57,)**
```

Why isnt it printing as (57,1).  How can I do that?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `[]`

```
result[:,[1]].shape
Out[284]: (2, 1)
```

---

Data input

```
result
Out[285]: 
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

---

More Information

```
result[:,[1]]
Out[286]: 
array([[2],
       [2]])
result[:,1]
Out[287]: array([2, 2])
```

Comment: @hydra123 if it is work would you like consider upvote and accept >_<

Comment: Yes i will but there is a 9 min window to it

Comment: Also I am getting same problem in w = np.zeros([57])

print(w.shape)  (57,)... How can I get (57,1)??

Comment: @hydra123 `np.zeros([57])[:,None].shape` this so called numpy broadcast

Answer (score 2):

yes it will return the array of shape (57,). If you want to be as (57,1) , you can do it so by reshape().

```
col1=(result[:, 1]).reshape(-1,1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`col1 = result[:, 1]` is 1D array, thus you see that the shape it `(57, )`.

You can convert it to a 2D array with a single column doing:

```
col1[:, np.newaxis]   # shape: (57, 1)
```

If you want a 2D array with a single row you can do:

```
col1[np.newaxis, :]   # shape: (1, 57)
```